# What languages can doxygen highlight in fenced code blocks

Tags: doxygen

What are the languages that Doxygen recognizes and highlights in a `@code/@endcode` block or a [fenced code block in markdown](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced)? I have been playing around and got these to work:

```
{cpp}, {py}, {xml}
```

I would like to also highlight cmake and bash snippets.  Is that possible, what are the corresponding extensions I would have to wrap with braces? For the record, I"m using doxygen 1.18.13

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is already a bit older (December 2016), the current version is 1.9.1. The mentioned "languages" cmake and bash are not directly known to doxygen so there is also no highlight support for these in doxygen (I wrote directly as maybe someone might have written a filter to support these "languages"). For a completer list of supported languages see the doxygen manual.

Comment: @albert So where in the manual does it say which languages are supported for highlighting? I found this "These languages are supported by default: C, C++, C#, Objective-C, IDL, Java, VHDL, PHP, Python, Fortran and D. " at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#step0 . But obviously XML is highlighted, too, so that comment is not complete

Comment: I think you are right. I was thinking about table in step 1 of the just below your reference, though besides the languages that are parsed and can be used in code sections there are a few, i.e. ".xml" and ".sql", that can be used, only, in code sections (so with highlighting).